# How can I find max value in an array using cases?

Tags: c, function

This code is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#define MAX 500

void hof (int *arr, int n);
int fm (int arr[], int index, int maximum);

int main (void) {
  int i;
  int n;
  int arr[MAX];
  //int size = sizeof (arr[MAX]) / sizeof (arr[0]);

  printf("How many elements to print: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i=0; i < MAX; i++) {
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
  //int maximum = arr[0];
  hof (&arr[0], n);

  int maximum = fm (arr, 0, n);
  printf ("the largest number of sequence is %d", maximum);
}

void hof (int *arr, int n) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == 1 )
      arr[i] = 1;
    else
      arr[i] = arr[i - arr[i-1]] + arr[i - arr[i - 2]];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("Q(%d)->%d\n", i + 1, arr[i]);

}

int fm(int arr[], int index, int maximum) {
  int max;
  if (index > maximum - 1) {
    if(arr[index] <= arr[index + 1])
      return arr[index];
    else
      return arr[index + 1];
  }
  max=fm(arr, index + 1, maximum);
  if (arr[index] >= max)
    return arr[index];
  else 
    return max;
}
```

I wrote the code that found the Hofstadter q sequence and gave the maximum value.However, case 2 does not show the maximum value after case 1 when I edit it as follows. How I can solve the problem? (For example I select n=7 first n term of q sequence,=1 1 2 3 3 4 5 then I want to find max value select case 2) 
Thanks...

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 500

void hof(int*arr, int n);
int fm(int arr[], int index, int maximum);
void menu() {
  int nu;
  int n;
  int maximum;
  int i;
  int arr[MAX];
  printf("               Please make your choice\n");
  printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
  printf("1) FILL ARRAY\n\n");
  printf("2) FIND BİGGEST VALUE\n\n");
  printf("3) CALCULATE SUM\n\n");
  printf("4) CALCULATE STANDART DEVİATİON\n\n");
  printf("5) EXIT\n\n");
  printf("please select one of them\n");
  scanf("%d",&nu);

  switch (nu) {
    case 1:
      //int i;  
      //int n;
      //int arr[MAX];   
      printf("How many elements to print: ");
      scanf("%d",&n);

      for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
      }

      hof (&arr[0], n);
      break;

    case 2:
      maximum = fm(arr, 0, n);
      printf ("the largest number of sequence is %d", maximum);

  }
}

int main () {
  menu ();
}

void hof (int*arr, int n) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == 1)
      arr[i] = 1;
    else
      arr[i] = arr[i - arr[i - 1]] + arr[i - arr[i - 2]];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("Q(%d)->%d\n",i+1,arr[i]);
}

int fm (int arr[], int index, int maximum) {
  int n;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == 1 )
      arr[i] = 1;   
    else
      arr[i] = arr[i - arr[i - 1]] + arr[i - arr[i - 2]];
  }
  int max;
  if (index > maximum - 1) {
    if (arr[index] <= arr[index + 1])
      return arr[index];
   else
     return arr[index+1];
  }
  max = fm (arr, index + 1, maximum);
  if (arr[index] >= max)
    return arr[index];
  else 
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Can you please do a proper code formatting? With this mixed indentation it is harder to follow the control flow.

Comment: Oops messed up format clean-up - post rolled back.

Comment: I indented the code and added spaces in the C style. This could seem overkilling, but when you have to debug code, it is very important to make the structure appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that since now you glued together the hof and fm functions into a new fm function this new extended fm function needs to know the number of elements to work with. Thus you'd have to do 2 modifications:

1) Add a prompt under menu point 2 that asks for the number of elements just like under menu point 1.

2) In the function fm change the limit of the first for loop from n to maximum(since this is how you call the parameter representing the length of the array). I also removed the line `int n;` as declaring n as a local variable serves no purpose in this context. It's because the fm function already receives the length of the array through its maximum parameter.

So the resulting code with these minor modifications would look like this(I marked the changed lines, 4 altogether, with arrows):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 500

void hof(int*arr, int n);
int fm(int arr[], int index, int maximum);
void menu() {
  int nu;
  int n;
  int maximum;
  int i;
  int arr[MAX];
  printf("               Please make your choice\n");
  printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
  printf("1) FILL ARRAY\n\n");
  printf("2) FIND BİGGEST VALUE\n\n");
  printf("3) CALCULATE SUM\n\n");
  printf("4) CALCULATE STANDART DEVİATİON\n\n");
  printf("5) EXIT\n\n");
  printf("please select one of them\n");
  scanf("%d",&nu);

  switch (nu) {
    case 1:
      //int i;
      //int n;
      //int arr[MAX];
      printf("How many elements to print: ");
      scanf("%d",&n);

      for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
      }

      hof (&arr[0], n);
      break;

    case 2:
      printf("How many elements to work with: "); // <==
      scanf("%d",&n); // <==
      maximum = fm(arr, 0, n);
      printf ("the largest number of sequence is %d", maximum);

  }
}

int main () {
  menu ();
}

void hof (int*arr, int n) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == 1)
      arr[i] = 1;
    else
      arr[i] = arr[i - arr[i - 1]] + arr[i - arr[i - 2]];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("Q(%d)->%d\n",i+1,arr[i]);
}

int fm (int arr[], int index, int maximum) {
  //int n; // <==
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < maximum; i++) { // <==
    if (i == 0 || i == 1 )
      arr[i] = 1;
    else
      arr[i] = arr[i - arr[i - 1]] + arr[i - arr[i - 2]];
  }
  int max;
  if (index > maximum - 1) {
    if (arr[index] <= arr[index + 1])
      return arr[index];
   else
     return arr[index+1];
  }
  max = fm (arr, index + 1, maximum);
  if (arr[index] >= max)
    return arr[index];
  else
    return max;
}
```